# jQuery .datepicker("setDate",newdate) is not triggering onChange nor onSelect events

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

The contents of the datepicker input is changed programmatically via "setDate" method and I want to update the preview of the input form depending on the changed date value.

The "onSelect" event is triggered only when the date is changed through the datepicker UI and not when "setDate" is called.

"onChange" event of the input is also not triggered.

Right now it seems the only way is to call my *updatePreview* function manually every time after the "setDate" and I have to re-format the date object I get from the "getDate" method.

Is there an easier way to do it?

Here's the mockup in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhZQk/4/). The "change programmatically" button doesn't update the preview.

Comment: Although I can mostly follow your question, adding some code to your question would help a lot. For example, I have no idea what else your _updatePreview_ function is doing. You could create a demo of your problem using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for example.

Comment: Great question, Rots! Thanks for posting it and your jsFiddle answer down below in a comment to the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to update a separate element with the date being entered or set programmatically. If so, [updating an alternate field](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#alt-field) *preview* is baked into jQuery UI Datepicker already.

The datepicker widget only seems to be able to update an alternate `<input>` field rather than a `<div>` *preview* though, so if you need it to update a `<div>` then this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bV5fu/) will require a bit more work.

Comment: I noticed that if I change the altField object to a div, the value is still being set. After a bit of digging in jQuery code I was able to register a hook and construct a callback object.
[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bV5fu/1/)
It's a bit ugly, but hey it works.

Answer (score 2):

You could trigger the event yourself, but in general setting values in javascript does not trigger events. This goes for jQuery too.
Firing the events yourself:

```
$(elem).select(); // for select obviously  
$(elem).change(); // for change
```

Comment: the select() opens the datepicker dialog and I don't want that

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean (with the jsFiddle-thing). No, I don't think there's a better way than calling the updatePreview()-method directly or indirectly (other than what andyb answered). But you could make a function for setting the date, that way you don't have to repeat code that often.